# en classe / dans la classe

Tags: sens

Bonjour,
Si je demande *tu es en quelle classe ?* la personne va me répondre *je suis en 3<sup>ème</sup>*.
Si je demande *tu es dans quelle classe?* je fais référence à un lieu (classe de dessin ou dans la classe A5, par exemple).

Est-ce que c'est juste ?

Comment: Oui, ça a l'air juste, ou du moins probable. J'aurais les mêmes intuitions.

Comment: I would perceive another distinction, perhaps not at odds with the first. With *en* I would understand *classe* to refer to the course, but with *dans* I would understand it to refer to the group of students. You're in (*en*) French, you're a member of (*dans*) the French class.

Comment: @LukeSawczak I agree for *en cours de français* vs *dans le cours de français*, but the Q is about *classe*. At least in Europe, asking about one's *classe* almost always means "grade/year", not "class/course".

Answer (score 2):

> Si je demande tu es en quelle classe ?, la personne va me répondre je suis en 3eme.

Oui.

> Si je demande tu es dans quelle classe?, je fais référence à un lieu (classe de dessin

Pas vraiment, j'utiliserais *dans quelle salle* ou *dans quel cours* (matière).

> ou dans la classe A5, par exemple)

si A5 est ton numéro de classe (au sens groupe d'élèves), oui. Si c'est un numéro de salle de classe, on dirait *dans quelle salle*.

Answer (score 0):

Je comprendrais la question, mais je te regarderais d'un drôle d'air. Pour moi *En classe* ou *en cours* est une construction équivalente à *en réunion* et signifie que j'y suis présent à ce moment exact. Pour moi, cette expression ne s'emploierait jamais avec un déterminant.